# How to set Current Month and year in my number picker index?

Tags: android

How to can I set the current month and year in my `NumberPicker` index ? I have two `NumberPicker` instances - the first is for the and second is for the year. Both are set as string arrays, but how do I set current position as the current month?

Here is my current code:

```
final String wheelMenu2[] = {
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
};

NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberpicker2);
numberPicker2.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker2.setMaxValue(wheelMenu2.length-1);
numberPicker2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true); 
numberPicker2.setDisplayedValues(wheelMenu2);

int posmonthwheel2 =numberPicker2.getValue();
s4 = wheelMenu2[posmonthwheel2];
```

Comment: final String wheelMenu2[] ={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}; NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberpicker2);
        numberPicker2.setMinValue(0);
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(wheelMenu2.length-1);
        numberPicker2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        numberPicker2.setDisplayedValues(wheelMenu2);
        int posmonthwheel2 =numberPicker2.getValue ();
        s4= wheelMenu2[posmonthwheel2];

Comment: post your code in your post, not as comment

Comment: Don't you just use `setValue`

Answer (score 1):

```
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

month will give have the value of the current month i.e, Jan, Feb, Mar etc. Use this to compare with your array and set it to the view

and for setting in your number formatter use the below method,

numberPicker.setValue(// int position value of the result);

Comment: It would be better to get the zero based integer of `Calendar.Month` and then use the result in `wheelMenu2[value]`